# How to distinguish between network image and file image in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm having a hard time distinguishing between network image and file image.

```
putImage(image){
    if(image.runtimeType == String){
    // if(image.contains('http')){
      imageInProfile = NetworkImage(image);
      return imageInProfile;
    } else{
      imageInProfile = FileImage(File(image));
      return imageInProfile;
    }
  }
```

I used 'image.runtimeType == String', however the network image and file image are both string type.
Then I tried contains method because most of the network image has 'http' or 'https', but it didn't work and cause error that type '_File' is not a subtype of type 'String'.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You say that both are `String` (url or path). But the error shows that you pass `File` type. Make sure you pass file path, not file object.

Comment: If you want a unified interface, you could have the caller always supply a `Uri` argument and then let your function choose between `NetworkImage` and `FileImage` based on whether it's a file URI.

Comment: How to let the function choose between NetworkImage and FileImage based on whether it's a file URI?

Comment: I have error that Class 'String' has no instance method 'isSheme'. How can I fix this?

Comment: As I said, I'd change your function to take a `Uri` instead of a `String`.  I also made a couple of typos in my earlier version; try: `return uri.isScheme('file') ? FileImage(File(uri.toFilePath())) : NetworkImage(uri.toString());`.  Alternatively, if you really want to take a `String` argument, then do `var uri = Uri.parse(image);` first.

Answer (score 1):

To check Valid URL string you just have to use Uri.parse() like below.

```
bool _validURL = Uri.parse(_adVertData.webLink).isAbsolute;
```

Comment: It's a valid url. I just want to show the image whether it's a file or URI

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will be receiving String URL of it is network image for the other it will be a File.

If yes, you can check file type like,

```
if(image is String)
```

This will check type of image object. if it is String, you should check for the url is http url,

```
Uri.parse(_adVertData.webLink).isAbsolute
```

This will return true if it is Http url.

Please let me know if this doesn't works for you

Update:

```
   Widget getImageBasedonType(String image){
    if(image.contains("http://") ||image.contains("https://")){
      return Image.network(image);
    }else{
      return Image.file(File(image));
    }
  }
```

here, I consider image will be network image or file path not the asset.

Comment: What is _adVertData and how can I use it. I wrote the code, but it makes red underline and not working

Comment: It is the image in your case. it is just the url you are getting. _adVertData.webLink is String

Comment: It works when the image is URI. However, when the image is a file, then it makes error that type '_File' is not a subtype of type 'String'. How can I fix this?

Comment: if(image is String) put this check before checking uri

Comment: Still not working. When I print the image, it says that 
File: '/data/user/0/com.HYcompany.fishgram/cache/image_picker6185496495376698484.jpg'
and causes error that type '_File' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Comment: Please check the update part in comment.

Comment: I put (image is String) before checking uri, but it doesn't work. I think the function thinks the file image is isValid = true. I tried to put(print 'something') inside of else function and didn't showed any text

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245654/discussion-between-abv-and-).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a getter like this one:

```
  bool get isNetworkImage {
    return Uri.tryParse(iconPath)!.host.isNotEmpty;
  }
```

and use it in your Widget like:

```
isNetworkImage ? SvgPicture.network(path) : SvgPicture.asset(path);
```

The getter checks if the string is a valid URL by checking if there is any host. Every valid URLs should have a host, whereas a relative path has no host.